# Create domain in WebLogic 12c

Tags: weblogic12c, weblogic11g

I installed WebLogic 12c and I tried to configure domain on Linux. But when I run configure.sh command I get no response.

```
bash-4.2$ /u01/app/oracle/12c/oracle_common/common/bin/config.sh  -mode=console
bash-4.2$
```

Can you give some advice what could be wrong?

Comment: Have you tried without "-mode=console" ? What happens if you do so?

Comment: again nothing. Other ideas?

Comment: What exactly happens? When you hit config.sh, do you get a return right away back to shell, or does it hang for a while?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have installed window manager ..X11 ,xming client..on your Linux and its running for console mode because -mode=console is correct and working.

Comment: Which packages are these?

Comment: one of simple how-to-do link , i found this one : http://adminoracle10g.blogspot.de/2013/04/how-to-install-and-configure-x11-on_18.html

Answer (score 0):

Please use VNC to login to your linux machine and invoke the config.sh script and it will take few seconds to launch the OUI installer, you need to be patient and also please check logs for any installer errors.